# Method 'MailEnvelope' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Tags: excel, ms-word, outlook, vba

I'm having issues with the code below. I commented it as much as I could. Thanks in advance for your help.

It hangs at:

```
Set MailSendItem = doc.MailEnvelope.Item
```

Where it gives the error Method 'MailEnvelope' of object '_Worksheet' failed. I tried saving the workbook before sending and it did not fix the issue. The issue began only once I incorporated:

```
.Attachments.Add ("H:\Thought Pieces\Small Cap Liquidity\A Closer Look at Small Cap Liquidity.pdf")
```

After it hangs, I can just hit resume and it will continue iterating through the Excel sheet and sending out the e-mails. Code works perfect otherwise. On Error Resume Next does not continue the sending, only manually resuming does.

```
Sub SendOutlookMessages()

 'Dimension variables.
 Dim OL As Object, MailSendItem As Object
 Dim W As Object
 Dim MsgTxt As String, SendFile As String
 Dim ToRangeCounter As Variant

 Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 Dim doc As Word.Document

 'On Error Resume Next

 'Assigns Word file to send
 Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
 If wd Is Nothing Then
 Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 blnWeOpenedWord = True
 End If
 Set doc = wd.Documents.Open _
 (Filename:="H:\Thought Pieces\Small Cap Liquidity\A Closer Look at Small Cap Liquidity.doc", ReadOnly:=False)
 Set itm = doc.MailEnvelope.Item

 'Starts Outlook session
 Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set MailSendItem = doc.MailEnvelope.Item


 'Creates message
 For Each xRecipient In Range("tolist")
    With MailSendItem
     .Subject = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("subjectcell").Text
     .Body = MsgTxt
     .To = xRecipient
     .Cc = xRecipient.Offset(0, 6)
     .Attachments.Add ("H:\Thought Pieces\Small Cap Liquidity\A Closer Look at Small Cap Liquidity.pdf")
     .Send
    End With
    Set MailSendItem = doc.MailEnvelope.Item
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"))
 Next xRecipient


 'Ends Outlook session
 Set OL = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of reading and testing things out...the answer is the following:

I have to close the prior instance of the document (and use the currently open MSWord object if I don't want to keep opening new MSWord processes).

I edited the 'Creates message section:

```
'Creates message
 For Each xRecipient In Range("tolist")
    With MailSendItem
     .Subject = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("subjectcell").Text
     .Body = MsgTxt
     .To = xRecipient
     .Cc = xRecipient.Offset(0, 6)
     .Attachments.Add ("H:\Thought Pieces\Small Cap Liquidity\A Closer Look at Small Cap Liquidity.pdf")
     .Send
    End With
    doc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

    Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    Set doc = wd.Documents.Open _
 (Filename:="H:\Thought Pieces\Small Cap Liquidity\A Closer Look at Small Cap Liquidity.doc", ReadOnly:=False)
    Set MailSendItem = doc.MailEnvelope.Item
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"))
 Next xRecipient
```

The part to take note of is:

```
    Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    Set doc = wd.Documents.Open _
 (Filename:="H:\Thought Pieces\Small Cap Liquidity\A Closer Look at Small Cap Liquidity.doc", ReadOnly:=False)
    Set MailSendItem = doc.MailEnvelope.Item
```